# Recovering Open Document Format Files and OLE in one go

Tags: data-recovery

Is there a recovery program that recovers both OLE files (MS Office files, i.e. .doc, .docx) and Open Document Format files (Libre/Open Office ones, i.e .odt) on Ubuntu 12.04?

I deleted these files with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Are you saying that you've deleted files and want to recover them, or that you closed a program and didn't save the files?

Specifically, what do you mean by OLE and open format files?

Comment: I deleted them with shift + delete with meaning to.  OLE files are the MS Office files (i.e. .doc, .docx) and Open Format are the Libre/Open Office ones (i.e .odt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try **foremost** as [described in the Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Extract_individual_files_from_recovered_image).

`sudo apt-get install foremost`

Assumed your deleted files are on /media/USB/ and you want to restore them to ~/Desktop/recovery/ run:

`sudo foremost -t ole,zip -i /media/USB -o ~/Desktop/recovery`

After that change ownership of that folder by

`sudo chown -R user:user ~/Desktop/recovery/`

whereat `user` is your username.

> From the mentioned wiki page: "zip: Note is will extract .jar files as well because they use a similar format. Open Office docs are just zip’d XML files so they are extracted as well. These include SXW, SXC, SXI, and SX? for undetermined OpenOffice files."

Comment: I know that, but does it recover open format files too?

Comment: From the mentioned wiki page: "zip: Note is will extract .jar files as well because they use a similar format. Open Office docs are just zip’d XML files so they are extracted as well. These include SXW, SXC, SXI, and SX? for undetermined OpenOffice files."

Comment: I see, I guess I should of read before throwing this question up.